# wxpython add splitter window to notebook page

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

I have adapted this for my own use:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Splitter Tutorial")

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        leftP = LeftPanel(splitter)
        rightP = RightPanel(splitter)

        # split the window
        splitter.SplitVertically(leftP, rightP)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now I want to add it as a page in a simple wxNotebook. Normally the notebook page would be set up something like:

```
p = wx.Panel(self)
nb = wx.Notebook(p)
page1 = module_name.module_Class(nb)
nb.AddPage(page1, "Tab label")
```

The splitter has two (three in my case) panel Classes but obviously I can't just call one of them. Can someone please explain how I can wrap it all up?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the splitter widget on a panel in its own class. Then you can add your panel with the splitter in it to a notebook widget. Here's an example:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class LeftPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        grid = gridlib.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(25,12)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(grid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        txt = wx.TextCtrl(self)

########################################################################
class SplitterPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        leftP = LeftPanel(splitter)
        rightP = RightPanel(splitter)
        # split the window
        splitter.SplitVertically(leftP, rightP)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Notebook Splitter Tutorial")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        splitter = SplitterPanel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(splitter, 'Splitter')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, you came to the rescue again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you should just add the splitter itself as a page.